# .net core 3.0 entity infinite loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-3.1

I have some issues with .net core entity while fetching data.

this is my controller code

```
_context.Hierarchies
    .Include(i => i.Children)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Parent == null)
    .ToList();
```

and this is my Model Class

```
   public class Hierarchy
    {
        public Hierarchy()
        {
            CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Children = new List<Hierarchy>();
        }
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public Organization Organization { get; set; }
        public List<Task> Tasks{ get; set; }
        public Hierarchy Parent { get; set; }
        public long? ParentId { get; set; }
        public List<Hierarchy> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my db context model builder

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Hierarchy>(hierarchy => {
                hierarchy.HasMany(c => c.Children)
                .WithOne(c => c.Parent)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
            });
```

When call my api result is

```
[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "category1",
        "description": null,
        "createdBy": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "passwordHash": "IR4uM8YiGpzevGjNYQHfFgFBkHqTqGy3rgCsA8d9LNZAmTItvy2l3MXSnPcXQD7QldV3X5GA/CKSF4mPCFkAYg==",
            "passwordSalt": "XWzpfAf8IA7wpgY+gtVHiGPxTX4avvn38VY7MFspMhAfPUwL1a9ctuSQcEPlRJKqfK/3yZRtPWUlMQV7XH0JHRd4bKFvH/NKpSr4v46vOlgdQWAZDH1dklmqPtCmYK/Rq8SC/qcKfrmQLbJewBJ7B1Fse33ohAXp29+0K1c4YsE=",
            "name": null,
            "avatar": null,
            "address": null,
            "aboutMe": null,
            "company": null,
            "job": null,
            "city": null,
            "country": null,
            "birthday": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "createdDate": "2020-04-08T02:38:40.288739",
            "userOrganizations": null,
            "ownerTasks": null,
            "assignedTasks": null,
            "assigneeTasks": null,
            "currentOrganization": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Default",
                "description": "",
                "createdDate": "2020-04-07T23:38:40.459297",
                "userOrganizations": [],
                "hierarchies": [
                    {
                        "id": 17,
                        "name": "category2",
                        "description": null,
                        "createdDate": "2020-04-08T02:09:46.1474742Z",
                        "tasks": [],
                        "parentId": 16,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "createdDate": "2020-04-08T02:09:34.54658",
        "organization": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Default",
            "description": "",
            "createdDate": "2020-04-07T23:38:40.459297",
            "userOrganizations": [],
            "hierarchies": [
                {
                    "id": 17,
                    "name": "category2",
                    "description": null,
                    "createdBy": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "email": "test@test.com",
                        "passwordHash": "IR4uM8YiGpzevGjNYQHfFgFBkHqTqGy3rgCsA8d9LNZAmTItvy2l3MXSnPcXQD7QldV3X5GA/CKSF4mPCFkAYg==",
                        "passwordSalt": "XWzpfAf8IA7wpgY+gtVHiGPxTX4avvn38VY7MFspMhAfPUwL1a9ctuSQcEPlRJKqfK/3yZRtPWUlMQV7XH0JHRd4bKFvH/NKpSr4v46vOlgdQWAZDH1dklmqPtCmYK/Rq8SC/qcKfrmQLbJewBJ7B1Fse33ohAXp29+0K1c4YsE=",
                        "name": null,
                        "avatar": null,
                        "address": null,
                        "aboutMe": null,
                        "company": null,
                        "job": null,
                        "city": null,
                        "country": null,
                        "birthday": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                        "createdDate": "2020-04-08T02:38:40.288739",
                        "userOrganizations": null,
                        "ownerTasks": null,
                        "assignedTasks": null,
                        "assigneeTasks": null
                    },
                    "createdDate": "2020-04-08T02:09:46.1474742Z",
                    "tasks": [],
                    "parentId": 16,
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "tasks": null,
        "parent": null,
        "parentId": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 17,
                "name": "category2",
                "description": null,
                "createdBy": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                    "passwordHash": "IR4uM8YiGpzevGjNYQHfFgFBkHqTqGy3rgCsA8d9LNZAmTItvy2l3MXSnPcXQD7QldV3X5GA/CKSF4mPCFkAYg==",
                    "passwordSalt": "XWzpfAf8IA7wpgY+gtVHiGPxTX4avvn38VY7MFspMhAfPUwL1a9ctuSQcEPlRJKqfK/3yZRtPWUlMQV7XH0JHRd4bKFvH/NKpSr4v46vOlgdQWAZDH1dklmqPtCmYK/Rq8SC/qcKfrmQLbJewBJ7B1Fse33ohAXp29+0K1c4YsE=",
                    "name": null,
                    "avatar": null,
                    "address": null,
                    "aboutMe": null,
                    "company": null,
                    "job": null,
                    "city": null,
                    "country": null,
                    "birthday": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "createdDate": "2020-04-08T02:38:40.288739",
                    "userOrganizations": null,
                    "ownerTasks": null,
                    "assignedTasks": null,
                    "assigneeTasks": null,
                    "currentOrganization": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Default",
                        "description": "",
                        "createdDate": "2020-04-07T23:38:40.459297",
                        "userOrganizations": [],
                        "hierarchies": []
                    }
                },
                "createdDate": "2020-04-08T02:09:46.1474742Z",
                "organization": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Default",
                    "description": "",
                    "createdDate": "2020-04-07T23:38:40.459297",
                    "userOrganizations": [],
                    "hierarchies": []
                },
                "tasks": [],
                "parentId": 16,
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

its going createdBy -> currentOrganization -> hierarchy

i dont need currentOrganization and hierarchy 
also createdBy object has user passwordHash

how can i customize my return value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont need currentOrganization and hierarchy also createdBy object has user passwordHash

It seems you do not want to show `currentOrganization`, `hierarchy` and `passwordHash` in `createdBy` object.

Here are two ways to choose the return value:

1.Use JsonIgnore Attribute:

```
public class Hierarchy
{
    public Hierarchy()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Children = new List<Hierarchy>();
    }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }       
    public Hierarchy Parent { get; set; }
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Hierarchy> Children { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    //more properties...
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public Organization CurrentOrganization { get; set; }
}
public class Organization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //more properties...
    public List<Hierarchy> Hierarchies { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var d = _context.Hierarchies
            .Include(i=>i.Organization)
            .Include(i => i.Children)
            .Include(i => i.CreatedBy)
            .Where(x => x.Parent == null)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToList();
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

2.Create new View Model:

ViewModel:

```
public class HierarchyViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public UserViewModel CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public Hierarchy Parent { get; set; }
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Hierarchy> Children { get; set; }
}
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var d = _context.Hierarchies
            .Include(i=>i.Organization)
            .Include(i => i.Children)
            .Include(i => i.CreatedBy)
            .Where(x => x.Parent == null)
            .Select(x => new HierarchyViewModel()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate,
                Description = x.Description,
                Name = x.Name,
                Parent = x.Parent,
                Children = x.Children,
                CreatedBy = new UserViewModel()
                {
                    Id = x.CreatedBy.Id,
                    Email = x.CreatedBy.Email
                },
                ParentId = x.ParentId,
                Organization = x.Organization
            }).ToList();
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "bbb",
    "description": "abb",
    "createdBy": {
      "id": 3,
      "email": "email2"
    },
    "createdDate": "2019-08-07T00:00:00",
    "organization": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "org1",
      "hierarchies": [
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "asd",
          "description": "sda",
          "createdBy": null,
          "createdDate": "2019-08-06T00:00:00",
          "parent": null,
          "parentId": 9,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    "parent": null,
    "parentId": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "aaa",
        "description": "aaa",
        "createdBy": null,
        "createdDate": "2019-08-06T00:00:00",
        "organization": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "org1",
          "hierarchies": []
        },
        "parent": null,
        "parentId": 9,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It should depends on how you are serializing your model. But in general, creating a DTO only returning related data can be the best choice in most case. In your case, DTO can include only IserId instead of User object. Besides, if you insist on returning the Database entity, you can set object values 'null' before returning or not 'including' unrelated objects while you are fetching the entity from database. .

Comment: So,I must use DTO only like viewmodel.When i returned some data.

Comment: Sure. A service should always serve DTO to external consumers and to internal consumers as well.